# Align objects with dynamic width in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I am generating an SVG that needs to include some dynamic text elements. The general structure is as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------
|               <rect> <text> <rect> <text>|
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
--------------------------------------------
```

or to be a bit clearer - it's the legend at the top of a chart:

[image]

The rectangles are just 5px by 5px colored boxes, however both text elements are dynamic in width. The 4 elements then need to be aligned to the right.

Is there a way to somehow 'float' the 4 elements next to each other. Everything I have looked at so far seems to indicate that each of these elements needs a explicit X and Y coordinate which I don't actually know until the text is rendered.

I'm aware that there are javascript options available ('getBBox()' etc) but wondered if there was anything I could do just using the SVG DOM itself?

Comment: Another way is to render the entire text in one line, with enough (non-visible) spacing for 5px-wide box between both text and right-align the text, ending 5px from the right edge

Comment: Not a bad thought Alvin. I'm not sure how I would know the X coordinate to place the rectangles though?

Comment: The x-position with `text-anchor="end"` starts 5px from the right edge. What's the width of the container? Full page?

Comment: The width of the container is 100% and there are multiple rect/text pairs. It's a legend for a chart - I've added a picture above for clarity.

Comment: You could very easily do this in HTML without SVG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my [solution](http://alkhoo-app.appspot.com/akfiddle/square_with_text.html) that doesn't have Javascript. Uses `font-awesome` with `<tspan>` to draw the entire text.

**update:** Added "roboto" font and `dy` for better alignment.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" width="400px" height="400px" >
  <text text-anchor="end" x="400" y="20">
    <tspan dy="1" font-size="8pt" font-family="roboto" class="fa fa-fw" fill="skyblue"> &#xf0c8;</tspan> 
    <tspan dy="-2" font-size="8pt" font-family="roboto" >Gross Profit % &nbsp;&nbsp;</tspan>
    <tspan dy="2" font-size="8pt" font-family="roboto" class="fa fa-fw" fill="green"> &#xf0c8;</tspan> 
    <tspan dy="-2" font-size="8pt" font-family="roboto" >Op. Profit % &nbsp;&nbsp;</tspan>
    <tspan dy="2" font-size="8pt" font-family="roboto" class="fa fa-fw" fill="orange"> &#xf0c8;</tspan> 
    <tspan dy="-2" font-size="8pt" font-family="roboto" >Net Profit after tax % </tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Alvin - clever thinking to use the font. Unfortunately it still has an external dependency so I think Paul is correct in saying that there is no layout capabilities built into SVG. This solution will prove helpful though.

Comment: To remove external dependency, `font-awesome` has a SVG equivalent which contains the glyph for `&#xf0c8;` (fa-square) that you add [manually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/glyph). The `<svg>` coding remain the same.  **TL;DR:** SVG layout needs javascript for proper alignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can right-align text using `text-anchor="end"`.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin">
  
    <rect x="462" y="2" width="36" height="36" fill="blue"/>
    <rect x="422" y="2" width="36" height="36" fill="green"/>
    <rect x="382" y="2" width="36" height="36" fill="red"/>
    <text x="378" y="15" font-size="15px" text-anchor="end">Some right justified text</text>
    <text x="378" y="35" font-size="15px" text-anchor="end">Shorter text</text>

</svg>
```

Comment: That's helpful - however in this case I have text and graphical elements interspersed on the same line which all need to be right aligned. The problem lies in the fact that the text is dynamic in width...

Comment: I must have misread your question. I thought your example said text-rect-rect-rect.  Anyway, the answer is no. You can't do this with just vanilla SVG.  SVG has no automatic layout like HTML.